# Git: automatically synchronize multiple servers

Tags: git, synchronization

I have a client who has a few Git repositories on their own server. Due to policy, I do not have access to those repositories, however. Then, on my own Git server, some of those repositories should be mirrored, so we can exchange work.

There is a server on the client's network that has access to both repositories. The goal now is to setup a synchronisation process that causes as little trouble as possible.

If it were a simple one-way sync, then we could just take one repository/server as the master and force-push to the other server. However, the situation requires that we need two-way sync. From this, several problems arise:

- What if one side deletes a branch? Depending on the sync order, the branch would just be re-created from the other side
- How would conflict resolution work? i.e. both sides committed on the same branch. Ideally, this would fall back on the user and force them to merge properly

There are a few ideas to work around this, but I'm putting the question here to try and see if there's any practices out there that would allow us to implement our scenario in a clean way.

Rough ideas of mine:

- Using namespaces:

  1. branch names would not be "master", "foo", "bar" etc, but would always be prefixed "client/master", "client/foo", "mycompany/master" and so on
  2. The client would only be allowed to push to client/* branches, and my company would only be allowed to push to mycompany/* branches.
  3. Synchronisation between the two namespaces would be manually done by the developers
- Using hooks: Implement hooks server-side to disallow pushing if the remote server's branch is in a different state (i.e. newer commits)